# Javascript unit test mock Height function

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to write a unit test that is testing viewport functionality. To determine viewport I am using these functions:

```
var windowTop = ($(window).pageYOffset || $(document).scrollTop);
var windowBottom = $(window).height() + windowTop;
```

In test code, I implemented the following:

```
var windowTop = 0;
var windowBottom = 500;
mockedWindow = {
    screenY: () => {return windowTop;},
    height: () => {return windowBottom;}
};
```

I return the mockedWindow if the element I am trying to access is window:

```
 else if(element === window) {
     return [mockedWindow];
 }
```

I keep getting the error: $(...).height is not a function

However this method of defining functions on other objects seems to work. Is there something I am missing for mocking this window function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that I did not mock out the correct selected object for my test, so the functions were missing. The code for this was:

```
mockedWindow = {
    screenY: () => {return windowTop;},
    height: () => {return windowBottom;}
};

myStub['$'] = (element) => {
    if (element === window.document) {
        return [mockedDocument];
    } else if(element === window) {
        return mockedWindow;
    }
};
```